# How to import a listing of dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, installation, dependencies

I am trying to set up eclipse for a project I am working on using [a set of online instructions](http://jact-r.org/node/4).

The instructions call for me to "import this listing of dependencies".

> Start up Eclipse and open the **Preferences**. Select **Install/Update -
>   Available Software Sites**. You will **Import** this [listing of dependenices](http://jact-r.org/sites/default/files/0715-dependencies.xml_.txt)
>   (change extension to '*.xml*'). This tells the update manager where to
>   look for things like Rhino (Javascript support), and GEF/Zest (for IDE
>   tools).

'Dependencies' links to an XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookmarks>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20150519210750/repository/" selected="true" name="Orbit-R20150519210750"/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/tools/gef/updates/releases/" selected="true" name="org.eclipse.gef.repository"/>
</bookmarks>
```

I am relatively new to the inner workings of Eclipse and am not sure what to do with this text.

Comment: FYI stackoverflow removes HTML-like elements (i.e. XML) if they're not within a code block. Fixed it for you.

Comment: the page is all white except for the text, and thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your window should look like this:

[image: Preferences]

Save the XML file from the website as e.g. `dependencies.xml` and click 'Import...' and select it.

Alternatively, add two entries:

```
Name:
Orbit-R20150519210750
Location:
http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20150519210750/repository/

Name:
org.eclipse.gef.repository
Location:
http://download.eclipse.org/tools/gef/updates/releases/
```

Make sure to select them.